# Event is getting split in Day and Week view of Full Calendar when start time around 11:00 PM

Tags: fullcalendar

Event is getting split in Day and Week view of Full Calendar  when start time around 11:00 PM.
[enter image to see error description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfEeZ.png)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal verifiable example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve? From tags, I'm assuming you have an issue with Fullcalendar library, but to get help, you will need to provide your code.

Comment: difficult to say with so little information. my first guess would be that the minTime and maxTime of your calendar overlap what causes your event to belong to both dates

Comment: what is the end date and time of the event? From the picture I would assume the event ends some time around 00:45 on the next day. The event data is likely something like `start: "2019-03-14 23:00:00", end: "2019-03-15 00:45"` or similar. In which case, what the calendar is showing you is totally correct and expected - it should . But without seeing your actual event data and calendar setup code we can't be sure precisely what is happening and why. So if you still think there is a problem please show your code. It's impossible to fix something we can't see. Thanks.

Comment: I am creating event by StartDate only.

Comment: Please refer jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/7hcdgz5b/ . The event is getting split for week and day.